# Return the max number of elements in a list of variously sized arrays

Tags: r

My goal is to write a simple function that accepts a list of an indefinite amount of arrays (and elements can be strings or numbers) and returns the number of elements in the array with the most elements.

In the list:

```
x <- list(c(1,2,3,4,5),
          c(1,2,3),
          c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
```

The answer would be 7 because the third array has the max amount of elements in the list.

Conceptually, I'm having a hard time applying the idea of element count to a singular array within a list. When I try, like in the example below, I count the number of all elements. The difficulty is that I can't use a loop to solve it, only functions like `sapply()` or built in functions - no importing or calling from other libraries. How do I count the number of elements in each array in a list and then use `max()` on it?

```
listMax <- function(x) {
  findMax <- sum(sapply(x,length))
  print(findMax)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lengths` to count length of each element in the list and then use `max`

```
max(lengths(x))
#[1] 7
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm so annoyed that it was literally the "s" in `lengths` that messed me up.

Answer (score 1):

```
max(unlist(lapply(x, length)))
```